# Why is a while(true) loop in a constructor actually bad?

Tags: c#, architecture

Albeit a general question my scope is rather C# as I am aware that languages like C++ have different semantics regarding constructor execution, memory management, undefined behaviour, etc.

Somebody asked me an interesting question which was for me not easily answered.

Why (or is it at all?) regarded as bad design to let a constructor of a class start a never ending loop (i.e. game loop)?

There are some concepts that are broken by this:

- like the principle of least astonishment, the user does not expect the constructor to behave like this.
- Unit tests are harder as you cannot create this class or inject it as it never exits the loop.
- The end of the loop (game end) is then conceptually the time where the constructor finishes, which is also odd.
- Technically such a class has no public members except the constructor, which makes it harder to understand (especially for languages where no implementation is available)

And then there are technical issues:

- The constructor actually never finishes, so what happens with GC here? Is this object already in Gen 0?
- Deriving from such a class is impossible or at least very complicated due to the fact that the base constructor never returns

Is there something more obviously bad or devious with such an approach?

Comment: It's ugly, but at least for sealed classes there isn't any big issue.

Comment: Why is it good? If you simply move your main loop to a method (very simple refactoring) then the user can write unsurprising code like this: `var g = new Game {...}; g.MainLoop(); `

Comment: @Brandin I am aware of that, refactoring into a public method is easy and solves the problem but it does no way explaining why it might be a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: Your question already states 6 reasons **not** to use it, and I'd like to see a single one in its favor. You could also ask why it's a bad idea to put a `while(true)` loop in a property setter: `new Game().RunNow = true`?

Comment: Extreme analogy: why we say that what Hitler did was wrong? Except for racial discrimination, starting WWII, killing millions of people, violence [etc etc for 50+ other reasons] he did nothing wrong.  Sure if you remove an arbitrary list of reason as to why something is wrong you may as well conclude that that thing is good, for literally anything.

Comment: With respect to garbage collection (GC) (your technical issue), there would be nothing special about it. The instance exists before constructor code is actually run. In this case the instance is still reachable, so it cannot be claimed by GC. If GC sets in, this instance will survive, and at each occurrence of GC setting in, the object will be promoted to the next generation according to the usual rule. Whether or not GC takes place, depends on whether (enough) new objects are being created or not.

Comment: Why are you using a constructor at all instead of a simple function?

Comment: I would go a step further, and say the while(true) is bad, regardless of where it is used.  It implies that there is no clear and clean way to stop the loop.  In your example, shouldn't the loop stop when the game is exited, or loses focus?

Comment: The purpose of constructors is to create things. When I write `Game g = new Game();` I expect `g` to hold a new `Game` object.

Comment: Why are you looking for something *more* obviously bad or devious?  Aren't the points you listed already bad and devious enough?  What is your standard of comparison here?

Comment: Worse yet, imagine if some future maintainer creates a derived class which overrides a virtual method which now depends on members of the derived class and which is called by the base constructor. (I didn't check this, I'd expect the application to crash or to allow undefined behavior in a managed environment)

Comment: A positive argument could be (if the constructor doesn't leak any references to `this`): Since no other thread can get a reference to the object (after all, it's still being constructed), you don't need any synchronization on member variables (which might otherwise become costly)

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I was too long in C++ undefined behaviour land and was expecting something odd here, which I did not yet comprehend.

Comment: @JonAnderson There's `break;` for that. I'm not saying you should put a `while(true)` loop in your constructor, but to say there is no clear and clean way to stop it is wrong.

Comment: @JonAnderson `while(true)` is put to good use in embedded microcontrollers, when there _is_ no end other than cutting power. For "normal" code, I agree.

Comment: Is it *actually* bad? That depends upon the language, its compiler (or interpreter), and possible unintended effects or undefined behavior. It might actually be fine. (It might actually not be.) The only problem here is that you're breaking established OO patterns and conventions, which always turns into a religious debate. So...could you do this? Maybe. Should you? Only if you don't mind being crucified by the community.

Comment: Why no public members? There could be threads.

Comment: I feel like all the answers boil down to "I can't imagine a use case, so don't use it". Do you actually have a use case that prompts you to do something like this in a constructor rather than a method or a function?

Comment: I wonder that this question wasn't closed for being just silly.

Comment: A generalisation of this would be an infinite loop in any method with a non-void return value. The presence of a return value (or the apparent ability to return an instance) is misleading if never returns a value.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

What is the purpose of a constructor? It returns a newly constructed object. What does an infinite loop do? It never returns. How can the constructor return a newly constructed object if it doesn't return at all? It can't.

Ergo, an infinite loop breaks the fundamental contract of a constructor: to construct something.

Comment: Perhaps they meant to put while(true) with a break in the middle? Risky, but legit.

Comment: I agree, this is correct - at least. from an academical point of view. Same holds for every function which returns something.

Comment: Imagine the poor sod that creates a sub-class of said class...

Comment: @JanDvorak: Well, that's a different question. The OP explicitly specified "never ending" and mentioned an event loop.

Comment: @JörgWMittag well, then, yeah, don't put that in a constructor.

Comment: @DocBrown: I think the important thing is the implicit contract of a constructor, or to look at it from the other side, programmer expectations. Unless you are a Haskell programmer, you expect a "function" (in the C sense of the word) to "do stuff" and to occasionally fail or fail to finish. That's just something we accept. (And in fact, even Haskell has infinite recursion, exceptions and `unsafePerformIO`.) But we don't expect a constructor to "do stuff". We expect it to construct a value, which is (conceptually) a very simple thing.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: What if the value to be constructed is the High Score of the game? ^^ (just some food for thought)

Comment: I've seen some hacky things in my time but this would need a hell of a good reason to justify. Principle of least astonishment indeed.

Comment: To be technically correct: a constructor does not return the corresponding object. The constructor is a function like any other. The difference is that it's executed automatically and immediately **after** object instantiation.

Comment: @Newtopian: Inheriting from such an object might be useful in C# because of the way the virtual table is handed; overriding methods called by the constructor is reasonable.

Comment: @Radu Murzea: When I attempted to implement a managed OO language I found at the assembly level it makes sense to have the constructor return the object. The arrangement prevented the outside code from ever being able to hold a reference to an unconstructed object. The way this worked was new was passed a pointer to the constructor as though it were an ordinary function.

Comment: @hoffmale that is a very esoteric point of view, but I would definitely consider it food for thought.

Comment: @Joshua: true, one could do it this way, but any code in the sub-class constructor would effectively never get called, basically meaning the sub-class never gets constructed....  I wonder what would happen if, in creating this sub-class, one were to use new fields not present in the base-class ?...  Then again, one could create an init function that can be overloaded to initialize knowing the constructor would not actually get called...  Sounds like an awful lot of trouble to get around not having to call start() on the instance returned by a simpler constructor.

Comment: There are a lot of advantages in doing things "by the book"...  Call me lazy but my favorite is not having to write a whole new book to teach others how to use my creation.

Answer (score 45):

> Is there something more obviously bad or devious with such an approach?

Yes, of course. It is unneccessary, unexpected, useless, unelegant. It violates modern concepts of class design (cohesion, coupling). It breaks the method contract (a constructor has a defined job and is not just some random method). It is certainly not well maintainable, future programmers will spend a lot of time trying to understand what is going on, and trying to guess reasons why it was done that way.

Nothing of this is a "bug" in the sense that your code does not work. But it will likely incur huge secondary costs (relative to the cost of writing the code initially) in the long run by making the code harder to maintain (i.e., hard to add tests, hard to reuse, hard to debug, hard to extend etc.).

Many/most modern improvements in software development methods are done specifically to make the actual process of writing/testing/debugging/maintaining software easier. All of this is circumvented by stuff like this, where code is placed randomly because it "works".

Unfortunately, you regularly will meet programmers which are completely ignorant of all this. It works, that's it.

To finish with an analogy (another programming language, here the problem at hand is to calculate `2+2`):

```
$sum_a = `bash -c "echo $((2+2)) 2>/dev/null"`;   # calculate
chomp $sum_a;                         # remove trailing \n
$sum_a = $sum_a + 0;                  # force it to be a number in case some non-digit characters managed to sneak in

$sum_b = 2+2;
```

What is wrong with the first approach? It returns 4 after a reasonably short amount of time; it is correct. The objections (together with all the usual reasons a developer may give to refute them) are:

- Harder to read (but hey, a good programmer can read it as easily, and we have always done it like this; if you want I can refactor it into a method!)
- Slower (but this is not in a timing critical place so we can ignore that, and besides, it's best to optimize only when necessary!)
- Uses much more resoures (a new process, more RAM etc. - but dito, our server is more than fast enough)
- Introduces dependencies on `bash` (but it will never run on Windows, Mac or Android anyways)
- And all the other reasons mentioned above.

Comment: "GC could well be in some exceptional locking state while running an constructor" - why? The allocator allocates first, then launches the constructor as an ordinary method. There's nothing really special about it, is there? And the allocator has to allow new allocations (and these could trigger OOM situations) within the constructor anyways.

Comment: @JanDvorak, Just wanted to make the point that there *could* be some special behaviour "somewhere" while in a constructor, but you are correct, the example I picked was unrealistic. Removed.

Comment: I really like your explanation and would love to mark both replies as answers (have at least an upvote). The analogy is nice and your trail of thought and explanation of secondary costs is it too but I regard them as auxiliary requirements for code (same as my arguments). Current state of the art is to test code, therefore testability etc is a de-facto requirement. But @JörgWMittag 's statement `fundamental contract of a constructor: to construct something` is spot on.

Comment: The analogy is not so good. If I see this I would expect to see a comment somewhere on why you are using Bash to do the maths, and depending on your reason it may be totally fine. The same wouldn't work for the OP, because you would basically have to put apologies in comments everywhere you used the constructor "// Note: constructing this object starts up an event loop that never returns".

Comment: _"Unfortunately, you regularly will meet programmers which are completely ignorant of all this. It works, that's it."_ So sad but so true. I think I can speak for all of us when I say the only substantial burden in our professional lives is, well, those people.

Comment: @Samuel, thanks for the praise. Yes, the accepted answer is the best one (objective, short...); I mainly needed to vent at that day, and this question was a delightful opportunity.

Answer (score 9):

You give enough reasons in your question to rule this approach out but the actual question here is "Is there something more obviously bad or devious with such an approach?"

My first though here was that this is pointless.  If your constructor never finishes, no other part of the program can get a reference to the *constructed* object so what's the logic behind putting it in a constructor instead of a regular method.  Then it occurred to me that the only difference would be that in your loop you could allow references to partially constructed `this` escape from the loop.  While this isn't strictly limited to this situation, it's guaranteed that if you do allow `this` to escape, those references will always point to an object that is not fully constructed.

I don't know whether the semantics around this kind of situation are well defined in C# but I would argue it doesn't matter because it's not something most developers would want to try to delve into.

Comment: I'd assume that the constructor is run after the object was created thus in a sane language leaking this should be perfectely well defined behaviour.

Comment: @mroman: it might be ok to leak `this` in the constructor - but only if you are in the constructor of the most derived class. If you have two classes, `A` and `B` with `B : A`, if the constructor of `A` would leak `this`, the members of `B` would still be uninitialized (and virtual method calls or casts to `B` can wreak havoc based on that).

Comment: I guess in C++ that can be crazy, yes. In other languages members receive a default value before they are assigned their actual values so while it's stupid to actually write such code the behaviour is still well defined. If you call methods that use these members you might run into NullPointerExceptions or wrong calculations (because numbers default to 0) or stuff like that but it's technically deterministic what happens.

Comment: @mroman Can you find a definitive reference for the CLR that would show that to be the case?

Comment: Well you can assign members values before the constructor is run so the object exists in a valid state with members assigned default values or values assigned to them before the constructor was even run. You dont need the constructor to initialize members. Let me see if I can find that somewhere in the docs.

Comment: I looked it up, section III.4.21 (for the newobj directive) indeed states that all member fields will be instantiated to `0`, `null` or the corresponding default value. That still doesn't mean that this will be expected by all member variables (esp. null references of the fields of a derived class)

Comment: @hoffmale So the variables are defined but it's not clear what effect this might have on something like GC.  Not so much whether it can be collected but more esoteric stuff like whether the object can be moved to a different location on the heap if the constructor hasn't completed.

Answer (score 2):

+1 For least astonishment, but this is a hard concept to articulate to new devs. 
At a pragmatic level, it is hard to debug exceptions raised within constructors, if the object fails to initialise it will not exist for you to inspect the state of or log from outside of that constructor.

If you feel the need to do this sort of code pattern, please use static methods on the class instead.

A constructor exists to provide the initialisation logic when an object is instantiated from a class definition. You construct this object instance because it as a container that encapsulates a set of properties and functionality that you wish to call from the rest of your application logic.

If you do not intend to use the object that you are "constructing" then what is the point of instantiating the object in the first place? Having a while(true) loop in a constructor effectively means you never intend for it to complete...

C# is a very rich object oriented language with many different constructs and paradigms for you to explore, know your tools and when to use them, bottom line:

> In C# do not execute extended or never-ending logic within constructors because... there are better alternatives

Comment: his doesn't seem to offer anything substantial over points made and explained in prior 9 answers

Comment: Hey, I had to give it a go :) I thought it was important to highlight that while there is no rule against doing this, you shouldn't by virtue of the fact that there are simpler ways. Most other responses focus on the technicality of why it is bad, but that's hard to sell to a new dev who says "but it compiles, so can I just leave it like that"

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently bad about it.  However, what will be important is the question of why you chose to use this construct.  What did you get by doing this?

First off, I'm not going to talk about using `while(true)` in a constructor.  There is *absolutely* nothing wrong with using that syntax in a constructor.  However, the concept of "starting a game loop in the constructor" is one which can cause some issues.

It's very common in these situations to have the constructor simply construct the object, and have a function which calls the infinite loop.  This gives the user of your code more flexibility.  As an example of the sorts of issues that can show up is that you restrict use of your object.  If someone wants to have a member object that is "the game object" on their class, they have to be ready to run the whole game loop in their constructor because they have to construct the object.  This might lead to tortured coding to work around this.  In the general case, you cannot pre-allocate your game object, and then run it later.  For some programs that's not an issue, but there are classes of programs where you want to be able to allocate everything up front and then call the game loop.

One of the rules of thumb in programming is to use the simplest tool for the job.  It's not a hard and fast rule, but it's a very useful one.  If a function call would have been enough, why bother constructing a class object?  If I see a more powerful complicated tool used, I assume the developer had a reason for it, and I will begin exploring what sorts of odd tricks you might be doing.

There are cases where this might be reasonable.  There may be cases where it is truly intuitive for you to have a game loop in the constructor.  In those cases, you run with it!  For example, your game loop may be embedded in a much larger program which constructs classes to embody some data.  If you have to run a game loop to generate that data, it may be very reasonable to run the game loop in a constructor.  Just treat this as a special case: it would be valid to do this because the overarching program makes it intuitive for the next developer to understand what you did and why.

Comment: If constructing your object requires a game loop, at least put it in a factory method instead. `GameTestResults testResults = runGameTests(tests, configuration);` rather than `GameTestResults testResults = new GameTestResults(tests, configuration);`.

Comment: @immibis Yes, that is true, except for the cases where that is unreasonable.  If you're working with a reflection based system that instantiates your object for you, you may not have the option to make a factory method.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that some concepts got mixed up and resulted in a not so well worded question.

The constructor of a class may start a new thread which will "never" end (though I prefer to use `while(_KeepRunning)` over `while(true)` because I can set the boolean member to false somewhere).

You could extract that method of creating and starting the thread into a function of its own, in order to separate object construction and the actual start of its work - I prefer this way because I get better control over access to resources.

You could also have a look at the "Active Object Pattern". In the end, I guess the question was aimed at when to start the thread of an "Active Object", and my preference is a de-coupling of construction and start for better control.

Answer (score 0):

Your object reminds me of starting [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx). The task object has a constructor, but it there are also a bunch of static factory methods like: `Task.Run`, `Task.Start` and `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

These are very similar to what you are trying to do, and it's likely this is the 'convention'. The main issue people seem to have is that this use of a constructor surprises them. @JörgWMittag says it *breaks a fundamental contract*, which I suppose means Jörg is very surprised. I agree and have nothing more to add to that.

However, I want to suggest that the OP tries static factory methods. The surprise vanishes and there is no *fundamental contract* at stake here. People are used to static factory methods doing special things, and they can be named accordingly.

You can provide constructors that allow fine grained control (as @Brandin suggests, something like `var g = new Game {...}; g.MainLoop();`, that accommodate users who don't want to start the game immediately, and maybe want to pass it around first. And you can write something like `var runningGame = Game.StartNew();` to make starting it immediately easy.

Comment: It means Jörg is *fundamentally* surprised, which is to say a surprise like that is a pain in the fundament.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is a while(true) loop in a constructor actually bad?

That's not bad at all.

> Why (or is it at all?) regarded as bad design to let a constructor of a class start a never ending loop (i.e. game loop)?

Why would you ever want to do this? Seriously. That class has a single function: the constructor. If all you want is a single function, that's why we have functions, not constructors.

You mentioned some of the obvious reasons against it yourself, but you left out the very biggest one:

**There are better and simpler options to achieve the same thing.**

If there are 2 choices and one is better, it doesn't matter by how much it is better, you chose the better one. Incidentally, that's why we <s>don't</s> almost never use GoTo.

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of a constructor is to, well, contruct your object. Before the constructor has completed, it is in principle unsafe to use any methods of that object. Of course, we may call methods of the object within the constructor, but then each time we do so, we have to make sure that doing so is valid for the object in its current half-baken state.

By indirectly putting all logic into the constructor, you add more burden of this kind onto yourself. This suggests that you did not design the difference between initialization and use well enough.

Comment: this doesn't seem to offer anything substantial over points made and explained in prior 8 answers